# Docker communication from one container to another

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I have two docker containers. I'm trying to curl between one and the other container.

I've set up a common network.

Here is my docker-compose:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    build: ./webapp/.
    container_name: storyweb
    command: python3 /app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./webapp/:/app/
    ports:
      - 8007:8000
    networks:
      - backend
    env_file:
      - ./.env.dev
  novnc:  
    container_name: dramatica
    build: ./dramatica/.
    environment:
      # Adjust to your screen size
      - DISPLAY_WIDTH=1200
      - DISPLAY_HEIGHT=800
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
    ports:
      - "8008:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./dramatica:/app
    networks:
      - backend
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - web 
    entrypoint: /app/entrypoint.sh
networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```

I'm tryin gto curl from inside vovnc container:

```
curl -i web:8007
```

I've also tried storyweb.

Any idea why this is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your server container runs a server process

```bash
python3 /app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

connections between containers need to go to that port 8000.  `ports:` aren't used or required here, and can be removed if you don't require the service to be directly accessible from outside containers on the same Docker network.

Comment: Oh okay. I still wanted access to both from the outside, I guess. Is that not possible?

Comment: You can leave the `ports:` line as is, if you want, and it will be accessible from outside Docker on port 8007 on the host's IP address.  But that has no effect on connections between containers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying the command `curl -i web:8007` from your host machine. It will not work. You try this command from inside a container. You can try the following method

1. `curl -i localhost:8007`
2. `docker-compose novnc curl -i web:8007`